# Get data from devices through bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth

I need to build a car android app that displays various data from users phones when they are paired with the app.  by various data I mean their contact list , battery status etc..

which API's do I need to implement to do that ? I have seen the Bluetooth API's but as I don't have any control over the phones that pair with my app , I need somehow to get that data automatically .

Comment: Without an app running on the user phone to which you can communicate, this seems impossible.

Comment: @LaMachine So how nowdays when you pair your phone with a car device it automatically shows your contacts , music files, etc.. ?

Comment: Your app needs to give permission to read your contacts.

Comment: @KristyWelsh by your app you mean the app on the car device?

Comment: Yes, any app needs to have the permission to read the contacts list.

Comment: @KristyWelsh so your saying all I need is the permission and I can read any phone's contact list when it is paired to my device ?

Comment: Not sure about that, but it is possible to read another device's contacts.  This: http://www.geeksquad.co.uk/articles/sony-xperia-transfer-contacts-data suggests that you will need a way to log into the other phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting from samsung forums:

*"Phone Book Access Profile, often referred to in specifications as PBAP or PBA, is the latest protocol in the Bluetooth family for synchronizing contacts between devices. Cars and phones that support this standard can sync your address book to enable your in-car hands-free system to match incoming calls to contact names, display caller photos, and retrieve information for name-based voice dialing. Cars can also handle SMS using the Message Access Profile. Supporting devices enable you to browse, send and receive texts from your Bluetooth device; some devices even read incoming texts aloud automatically."*

So, check whether this bluetooth profile is supported by both bluetooth devices.

Android SDK documents support for a few profiles. See here:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html#Profiles

And apparently PBAP is not there. So, I would say, you are pretty much on your own - however, I stumbled onto this. Check it out:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/ee0b3e9/core/java/android/bluetooth/BluetoothPbap.java

Comment: I know of this profile and I know of other profiles. 
what I don't know is which Android API's use these profiles. and not just for phone book. for other data as well..